# GLSL 4.0 LWJGL Subroutine returning no uniform Subroutine index

Tags: glsl, lwjgl, subroutine

Hello I am following along my C++ GLSL shader cookbook and writing them in LWJGL, I ran across a problem with getting  glGetSubroutineIndices for my shader sub routines so I went to http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/glsl-core-tutorial-subroutines/
to get a very simple example and still cannot get the index, they always return a -1!!.

here is the Shader

```
#version 400

layout (std140) uniform Matrices {
mat4 pvm;
} ;

in vec4 position;

out vec4 color;


// the signature
subroutine vec4 colorRedBlue ();
subroutine uniform colorRedBlue myRedBlueSelection;
// option 1
subroutine (colorRedBlue ) vec4 redColor() {

    return vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
} 

// option 2
subroutine (colorRedBlue ) vec4 blueColor() {

    return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
void main()
{
    color = myRedBlueSelection();
    gl_Position = pvm * position ;
}
```

and here is the call to retrieve the location

```
System.out.println( GL40.glGetSubroutineIndex(programID, VertexShaderID, "redColor"));
System.out.println(GL40.glGetSubroutineIndex(programID, VertexShaderID, "blueColor"));
```

I am properly linking and retrieving all my other uniforms but THIS!, always returns a -1!!!.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `glGetSubroutineIndex()` is the shader **type**, not a shader name. So the calls should be:

```
GL40.glGetSubroutineIndex(programID, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "redColor"));
GL40.glGetSubroutineIndex(programID, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "blueColor"));
```